# Find object in array-valued property including prototypes

Tags: javascript, indexof

I have an array of object as property of my object:

```
myObject.columns = [{} , {} , ...];
```

MyObject also has this property (columns) in base prototype.

I want something like `indexOf()` that iterate over columns properties (object and all its prototypes like `hasOwnProperty()` functionality) and return the `index` if the object exists. How can I do that?

Comment: does this work `for (var key in myObject) { var value = myObject[key] }`

Comment: have you used `__proro__` in your code to assign columns or it simply comes from the base prototype object?

Comment: @MehranHatami simply comes from prototype

Comment: I assume "__proro__" is a misspell of "__proto__" since 'r' and 't' are right next to each other on the keyboard.

Comment: Ok then, no problem, because it is not a good practice to use `__proro__` to modify your base prototype object.

Comment: Can you show a real use case, with a filled in array of objects and a hypothetical call to this indexOf() function you'd like?  It seems so obvious to me what to do that I figure I must be misunderstanding what you want to do.

Comment: Just to clarify the question, let's say you have `myObject.columns = [{x:1, y:2} , {x:11, y:20}];` then you want to find a column which its `key` value is `11`, then your desired function should return `1` which is the `indexOf` of the container object. Is it what you want?

Comment: @MehranHatami yes, with this condition that iterate over all prototype objects on column property.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you'd like to be able to write?  For example: var i = myObject.indexOf('11')? or var i = myObject.indexof({ x : 11 })?

Comment: I don't see what the use case is for working through members of myObject obtained from the prototype, given that the prototype of myObject is probably Object.

Comment: @user1329482 second one; myObject.indexof({ x : 11 })

Comment: Okay, now I have something to work with.  Give me a few minutes.

Comment: @Mohammadreza: check out my answer then you can use it even for more than one criteria.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot simultaneously access the local value and the value from the prototype. The local value shadows (hides) the value in the prototype. To put it another way, there is no notion of automatically combining or concatenating elements of an array-valued property on the object and an array-valued property by the same name on its prototype. You'll have to do it yourself. To combine the local value of the property and its value on the prototype:

```
var combined_columns = this.columns.concat(this.constructor.prototype.columns);
```

Now you can look up the value in the concatenated array:

```
var find_object = find_object_in_array(combined_columns, object);
```

Writing `find_object_in_array` is left as an exercise.

#### Going all the way up the chain

But that only deals with the immediate prototype. If you want to get the concatenation of the `columns` properties from all prototypes in the chain:

```
function concat_values_from_proto_chain(obj, prop) {
    var result = [];
    while (obj) {
        result = Array.prototype.concat.apply(result, obj[prop]);
        obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now you can look for your object in `concat_values_from_proto_chain(this, 'columns')`. (Note that the awkward-looking `Array.prototype.concat` is a way of handling undefined (absent) and null values without having to make a special test for them.)

But `concat_values_from_proto_chain` combines two separate problems: walking the prototype chain, and extracting the value from each. It would be better practice to separate these two problems, and first write a routine which just obtains the prototype chain:

```
function get_proto_chain(obj) {
    var result = [];
    while (obj) {
        result.push(obj);
        obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
    }
    return result;
}
```

But even this routine intertwines two distinct aspects: calling a function repeatedly on the most recent value, and finding an object's prototype. To separate these two aspects as well, and create generic, useful routines we can use in the future, we write a little function which takes a function and whose only job in life is to keep calling that function on the most recent value and return the series of results in an array:

```
function get_function_series(fn, value) {
    var result = [];
    while (value) {
        result.push(value);
        value = fn(value);
    }
 }
```

If we were in a ES6 state of mind, we might want to write this as a generator:

```
function* get_function_series(fn, value) {
    while (value) { yield value = fn(value); }
}
```

We can now rewrite `get_proto_chain` concisely as

```
function get_proto_chain(obj) {
    return get_function_series(Object.getPrototypeOf, obj);
}
```

Then concatenating the property values for each member of the prototype chain is just

```
function concat_values_from_proto_chain(obj, prop) {
    return get_proto_chain(obj)                // loop over prototypes
        .map(function(o) { return o[prop]; })  // pull out the prop we want
        .reduce(Function.prototype.apply.bind(Array.prototype.concat), []);
                                               // concat them all down into one big array
}
```

If the `reduce` line is too much to deal with, then it can be replaced with

```
.reduce(function(result, val) {
    return val ? result.concat(val) : result;
}, [])
```

#### Example

```
function A () { }
var a = new A;
A.prototype.columns = [3, 4];
a.columns = [1, 2];

concat_values_from_proto_chain(a, 'columns)
> [1, 2, 3, 4]

Object.prototype.columns = [5, 6];
concat_values_from_proto_chain(a, 'columns')
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

#### Using a getter to automatically concatenate property values up the chain

What is we want `this.columns` to automatically return the concatenated values of the `columns` property on all prototypes? We can do this using a getter. We will need to introduce another property named `_columns` to hold the actual value.

```
object.defineProperty('columns', {
    columns: {
        get: function() { 
            return this._columns.concat(
                concat_values_from_proto_chain(this.getPrototypeOf(this), 'columns'); 
        },
        set: function(v) { this._columns = v; }
    }
});
```

If we want to be able to easily specify this behavior for other properties:

```
function define_concatenated_property(obj, prop) {
    return object.defineProperty(prop, {
        columns: {
            get: function() { 
                return this['_'+prop].concat(
                    concat_values_from_proto_chain(this.getPrototypeOf(this), 'columns'); 
            },
            set: function(v) { this['_'+prop] = v; }
        }
    });
}
```

Now:

```
function A()
var a = new A;
define_concatenated_property(a, 'columns');
a.columns = [1, 2]; // sets _columns property
A.prototype.columns = [3, 4]
a.columns // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

As it is obvious in your code `columns` is an array so you can iterate over it like:

```
function indexOfCompared(array, compareObj) {
  var i = 0,
    len = array.length,
    item,
    prop,
    found = false;

  for (; i < len; i++) {

    item = array[i];

    if (typeof item !== 'object') {
      continue;
    }

    for (prop in compareObj) {
      if (compareObj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {

        //this simply walks through all the prototype chain
        //and will find the key if the main object
        //or any of its base prototype objects have it
        found = item[prop] === compareObj[prop];
        if (!found) {
          break;
        }
      }
      if (found) {
        return i;
      }
    }
  }

  return -1;
}

myObject.columns = [{x:1, y:2, z:3} , {x:11, y:20, z:30}];

console.log(indexOfByKey(myObject.columns, {x:11}));
```

This way you can find your desired column based on even more than one criteria.

```
console.log(indexOfByKey(myObject.columns, {x:11, y:20}));//1
console.log(indexOfByKey(myObject.columns, {x:11, y:2}));//-1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MyObject.prototype.indexOf = function (o) {
    var key = Object.keys(o)[0], /// ES5 only
        val = o[key],
        ret = -1;
    this.columns.some( function (el,i) {
        if (key in el) {
            if (el[key] == val) {
                ret = i;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    });
    return ret;
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1j4a3c6d/

This is an ES5-only solution, but only because it uses Object.keys() has a quick way of determining what the key is in the argument to indexOf().  There are other, somewhat more hackish, ways of doing that.

Answer (score -1):

I was not sure what you were trying to do, but if you are trying to do what the below comment suggests, then this code will help you:

```
var myObject = {};
myObject.columns = [
    {name: "joe", lastName: "Boe"} ,
    {color: "blue", height: "100"}
];
function returnIndex(propertyName) {
    for (var i = 0; i < myObject.columns.length; i += 1) {
        for (var property in myObject.columns[i]) {
            if (myObject.columns[i].hasOwnProperty(property) && property === propertyName) {
            return i;
            }
        }
     }
 }

alert(returnIndex("height")); //1
```

Comment: I assumed the idea is to return an index into columns[], not the index of a property.  If property 'x' was found in columns[1], then return 1.

Comment: I guess the idea is that if you are not sure what the OP was trying to do, then make up a different question and answer it instead?

Comment: I was trying to help, in any case, the op should have made a way better job explaining,. keep using that credit for votedowns until you find something better to do